# Plotting multiple random walks

Tags: r

I am new to R and watched a YouTube video with the following code:

```
require(yuima)
m1 <- setModel(drift='mu*s', diffusion='sigma*s', 
   state.var='s', time.var='t', solve.var='s', xinit=100)   
x <- simulate(m1, true.param = list(mu=.1, sigma=.2))  
plot(x)
```

The above is mu multiplied by s, and sigma multiplied by s.
I am trying to plot 1000 of these simulations onto one plot with multi-colored lines.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do this, but I ended up digging into the simulated object and pulling out the pieces I needed.  (In general this is dangerous/bad practice; if the package authors give you accessor methods that get the bits you want, you should use them instead.)

Setup:

```
require(yuima)
m1 <- setModel(drift='mu*s', diffusion='sigma*s', 
   state.var='s', time.var='t', solve.var='s', xinit=100)
```

A function to run one simulation and return the data (`simulate` does have an `nsim` argument, but it doesn't do anything in this case ...)

```
simhack <- function() {
    s <- simulate(m1, true.param = list(mu=.1, sigma=.2))
    return(s@data@zoo.data[[1]])
}
```

Run 1000 times - automatically combines the results into a 1000-column matrix:

```
r <- replicate(1000,simhack())
```

Plot:

```
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
matplot(r,type="l",lty=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you very much.

Comment: technically comments aren't for "thank yous" -- to show your appreciate, accept the answer (click the checkmark) and/or upvote